# Sonarlint recommends to remove serialVersionUID in exception classes

Tags: java, exception, serialversionuid

I have a class `MyGenericException` that extends `Exception`:

```
public class MyGenericException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7332351790980555724L;

    private final String code;

    public MyGenericException(final String code, final String message) {
        super(message);
        this.code = code;
    }

    public MyGenericException(final String message) {
        super(message);
        this.code = "MY ERROR";
    }
}
```

Then I have another class, called `MyBusinessException` that extends `MyGenericException`:

```
public class MyBusinessException extends MyGenericException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7332567890980555724L;

    public MyBusinessException() {
        super("MY_BUSINESS_EXCEPTION_ERROR", "Throwing MyBusinessException!");
    }

    public MyBusinessException(String code) {
        super(code, "Throwing MyBusinessException!");
    }
}
```

I have a warning from Sonarlint on both classes that says: "Remove this serialVersionUID: *"serialVersionUID" should not be declared blindly*

Why should I remove the serialVersionUID?

Comment: Why should you have it?

Comment: Anyway, the [rule itself](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/RSPEC-4926) explains why you should remove it pretty well.